How to Update Order Date to Reflect Actual Placement Time in WooCommerce Block-Based Checkout?
I’m using the new WooCommerce block-based cart and checkout pages. I noticed that if a customer adds items to their cart, visits the cart or checkout page, and then leaves without placing the order right away, the order date is set to when they first visited the cart or checkout page. If they return a few minutes or even days later to complete the order, the order date does not update to the actual checkout time.
I want the order date to reflect the actual time the order is placed, not when the customer first visited the checkout. How can I adjust this behavior using a code snippet in functions.php or another solution?
Any help is appreciated!
